# Excel countif based on subsets

Tags: excel, countif

I am trying to count the number of companies we support based on their NAICS code (industry classification code). When a company signs up they provide either their 3,4,5 or 6-digit NAICS code.

For example, let's say I have three companies who joined. One of them provides its six-digit NAICS code `311811` (retail bakeries); another also provides its six-digit code `311812` (Commercial Bakeries); and the last one chooses only to provider its three-digit code `311` (food manufacturing).

In my spreadsheet the list of all the companies who join is in Sheet "RawData" and the NAICS code in Column J. The list of all NAICS codes is on Sheet "List" of my workbook, which is where I would like to return the result of total companies within a NAICS code.

A simple sumif function `=COUNTIF(RawData!J:J,List!A1)` returns only the count of organizations that joined based on an exact match of the code. In other words I get this:

```
Code   Count
311    1
3118   0
31181  0
311811 1
311812 1
```

What I really want to get get is

```
Code   Count
311    3
3118   2
31181  2
311811 1
311812 1
```

In the latter table the two companies that selected `311811` and `311812` should be counted in the count for the 311 code and the `3118` and `31181` codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following array formula in cell `B2` to get the count of `311` if `311` is in cell `A2`:

```
=SUM(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(A2,J:J)),0,1))
```

Note, that the above is an array formula and needs to be entered as such using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (instead of just pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>). You will see that Excel recoginzes the formula as an array formula by automatically adding curved brackets around the formula like so (do NOT manually enter these curved brackets):

```
{=SUM(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(A2,J:J)),0,1))}
```

<sub>Of course the above can be expanded upon by dragging the formula down and adding in column `A3` the value `3118` in cell `A4` the value `31181` and so on.</sub>